# Javascript synchronous loop in browser

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, greasemonkey, synchronous

Trying to automate a task in the browser with Greasemonkey.

Requirement: load a web page which contains a table displaying 15 out of 340+ results, with button controls to see the next page worth of results, go back, go to the end and so forth.

1. Collect the first 15 results --> got this working
2. Click on the 'Next' button  --> got this working
3. **Wait** until the page loads the next set of results --> **dont know how**
4. Repeat until the next button is disabled --> got this working

Cant show pictures cuz its a corporate app.

So far if I loop with setTimeouts, the timeouts get queued up and executed at the same time I think. Instead, the requirement is for the code to run the info collection, click next, wait, then collect info again.

Comment: -why wait for the page to load next 15 results? !

Answer (score 0):

You could try a utility function [waitForKeyElement](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2625891), a greasemonkey utility script.  It is essentially doing what you were trying to do before. It sets a timeout to continuously checks to see if an element is loaded. Executing it would look something like this:

```
waitForKeyElements (
     "div.comments", 
     commentCallbackFunction
);
```

Where comment callback function would be the function that collects results.

It would help also to understand why setTimeout in a loop doesn't work.  setTimeout does not block execution of a script to run your callback function.  It queues up that function to be executed no earlier than the time that you pass in as a second parameter.  Because of this, the loop runs very quickly and instead of getting function calls at `3000ms, 6000ms, and 9000ms...` as you might expect you get something closer to function calls at `3000ms, 3001ms, 3002ms`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute arbitrary JS logic mixed with API calls, recursion and timeouts **sequentially** via synchronous executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs):

```js
function synchronousCode() {
    var i=0;
    while(true) {
      console.log("waiting 1 sec, iteration", i++);
      $('#myDiv').toggle();
      nsynWait(nsynjsCtx,1000);
    };
}

var ctx;
function btnStopClicked() {
    ctx.stop();
    ctx=null;
}

function btnStartClicked() {
    ctx=nsynjs.run(synchronousCode,{},function(){
   console.log("Synchronous Code done");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amaksr/nsynjs/master/nsynjs.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/amaksr/nsynjs/master/wrappers/nsynWait.js"></script>
<body>
  <button id="buttonStart" onclick="btnStartClicked()">Start</button>
  <button id="buttonStop" onclick="btnStopClicked()">Stop</button>
  <div id="myDiv">Flashing div</div>
</body>
```

See more examples here: https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0):

Thanks people, found this post to be the best answer
[Synchronous setTimeout + Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563618/synchronous-settimeout-loop)

This way the page loads, the first values are read, the next button is clicked, next results appear and are read, until the last page.

Thanks again for the input and ideas

Answer (score 0):

you can use it

```
for(const elment of arrayElements) {
            await yourFunc(elment)
            await yourOtherFunc('somePatameter')
}
```